# NextJS: can't style Link with styled-components

Tags: next.js, styled-components

I keep getting the 'Hydration failed' error when trying to put a styled anchor element within the **Link** component. I've seen similar questions here but all answers point to giving the **passHref** property to **Link** and that doesn't seem to work for me.

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Layout.tsx

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import { A } from "../styles/General";
import { Footer, Header, Nav } from "../styles/Layout";

type LayoutProps = {
  children?: any;
  title?: string;
};

export default ({
  children,
  title = "This is the default title",
}: LayoutProps): ReactElement => (
  <>
    <Head>
      <title>{title}</title>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    <Header>
      <Nav>
        <Link href="/" passHref>
          <A>Home</A>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/about" passHref>
          <A>About</A>
        </Link>
      </Nav>
    </Header>
    {children}
    <Footer>
      <hr />
      <span>I'm here to stay (Footer)</span>
    </Footer>
  </>
);
```

A element

```
export const A = styled.a`
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

Comment: What version of Next.js are you using? Next 13 does not require an anchor tag within `Link` components.

Comment: It's 13 the latest one and I just found out i can style the Link component directly instead of using an 'a' element.

Answer (score 1):

I found out i can directly style the Link object and not use an anchor element. Not shure if it's a next version 13 thing or something but:

i changed this:

```
export const A = styled.a`
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

to this:

```
export const A = styled(Link)`
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

And used the **A** component as the **Link** component.

Comment: Yes, the anchor tag is built into Link in Next 13, so it is no longer required.